# How to input text to ModalDialog in Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog, webdriver

I got some trouble here. I can't input text to fill in the blank of modalDialog in webdriver.

This is an interface of my modalDialog :[image: my modalDialog]

I have been trying like this :

```
WebDriverWait  block = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    WebElement     modal = block.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("tambahbarang")));
    WebElement input;
    input    = modal.findElement(By.id("nama"));
    input.sendKeys("Kursi Kayu Jati");
    input    = modal.findElement(By.id("jenis"));
    input.sendKeys("Furniture");
    input    = modal.findElement(By.id("suplier"));
    input.sendKeys("CV Golden Wings");
    input    = modal.findElement(By.id("modal"));
    input.sendKeys("350000");
    input    = modal.findElement(By.id("harga"));
    input.sendKeys("500000");
    input    = modal.findElement(By.id("jumlah"));
    input.sendKeys("2");

    input    = driver.findElement(By.id("submit"));
    input.click();

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.quit();
```

but still not work.. can you help me, please. Thanks

Comment: Please check whether the Dialog-box is under any iframe or Paste the HTML..

Comment: @Ab123 i can't paste my code in here cause there is alert too much code than my statement.